# The difference between the code running on Linux and windows

Tags: c++, linux, c++17

ThreadPool in this code is a thread pool class。
I got different results when running in the Linux environment and the Windows environment, and a segment fault occurred when running in the Linux environment.
The result of running the above code on Windows will be

```
Start A的地址:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Deal A的地址:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Read A的地址:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The result in the Linux environment is

```
Start A的地址:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Deal A的地址:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
segmentation fault
```

```
template<typename T>
class SafeQueue {
public:
    bool empty() {
        shared_lock<shared_mutex>lc(_m);
        return _que.empty();
    }
    auto size() {
        shared_lock<shared_mutex>lc(_m);
        return _que.size();
    }
    void push(T& t) {
        unique_lock<shared_mutex> lc(_m);
        _que.push(t);
    }
    bool pop(T& t) {
        unique_lock<shared_mutex> lc(_m);
        if (_que.empty())return false;
        t = move(_que.front());
        _que.pop();
        return true;
    }
private:
    queue<T>_que;
    shared_mutex _m;
};
class ThreadPool {
private:
    class worker {
    public:
        worker(ThreadPool* _pool) : pool{ _pool } {}
        void operator ()() {
            while (!pool->_isShutDown) {
                {
                    unique_lock<mutex> lock(pool->_m);
                    pool->_cv.wait(lock, [this]() {
                        return this->pool->_isShutDown ||
                            !this->pool->_que.empty();
                        });
                }
                function<void()>func;
                bool flag = pool->_que.pop(func);
                if (flag) {
                    func();
                }
            }
        }
    private:
        ThreadPool* pool;
    };
public:
    ThreadPool(int n) : _threads(n), _isShutDown{ false } {
        for (auto& t : _threads)t = thread{ worker(this) };
    }
    ThreadPool(const ThreadPool&) = delete;
    ThreadPool(ThreadPool&&) = delete;
    ThreadPool& operator=(const ThreadPool&) = delete;
    ThreadPool& operator=(ThreadPool&&) = delete;

    template <typename F, typename... Args>
    auto submit(F&& f, Args &&...args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))> {
        function<decltype(f(args...))()> func = [&f, args...]() {return f(args...); };
        auto task_ptr = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(f(args...))()>>(func);
        std::function<void()> warpper_func = [task_ptr]() {
            (*task_ptr)();
        };
        _que.push(warpper_func);
        _cv.notify_one();
        return task_ptr->get_future();
    }
    ~ThreadPool() {
        auto f = submit([]() {});
        f.get();
        _isShutDown = true;
        _cv.notify_all();
        for (auto& t : _threads) {
            if (t.joinable()) t.join();
        }
    }

private:
    bool _isShutDown;
    SafeQueue<std::function<void()>> _que;
    vector<std::thread>_threads;
    mutex _m;
    condition_variable _cv;
};

class A {
public:
    int a = 0;
    void P() {
        cout << 111 << endl;
    }
};

class T {
public:
    T(int num) : mThreadPool(new ThreadPool(8)) {

    };

    void Start() {
        A a;
        cout << "Start A的地址:" << &a << endl;
        Deal(a);

    }

    void Deal(A& a) {
        cout << "Deal A的地址:" << &a << endl;
        mThreadPool->submit(std::bind(&T::Read, this, std::ref(a)));
    }

    void Read(A& a) {
        cout << "Read A的地址:" << &a << endl;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<ThreadPool> mThreadPool;
};

int main() {

    T t(8);
    t.Start();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace at the segfault.

Comment: In `Start` you create a local `A a`, then you hand a reference to that `a` to `Deal` who then further passes the reference on to `submit` - it is references all the way, with no copies being made (that I can see). So when `Start` finishes `a` is destroyed and all your references become dangling.

Comment: Remember that Linux and Windows behaves differently when the main thread terminates. On Linux all threads are killed, on Windows they keep running.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the crash is undefined behavior.

```
mThreadPool->submit(std::bind(&T::Read, this, std::ref(a)));
```

This will eventually call `T::Read` in a new execution thread.

However `a` is an object in automatic scope that will be destroyed shortly after this returns, leaving a dangling reference behind. `Deal()` returns, then `Start()` returns. Goodbye, `a`! Another execution thread needs to poke at `a` later? Too bad.

The shown code does not ensure that `a` remains in scope until the execution thread accesses it. The likely reason for the crash is that `a` gets destroyed before the execution thread accesses it, resulting in undefined behavior.

Additionally, it appears that the shown code also does not ensure that `this` remains in scope, either, for the duration of the execution thread. The `this` object appears to be an automatically-scoped object in `main` that will simply be destroyed, when `main` returns, with nothing in the shown code ensuring that the execution thread finished before this happens (and, on hindsight, this is probably the actual reason for the crash, since this nukes all sorts of important stuff, like the `std::queue`, the `std::mutex`, and all other sorts of critical metadata).

In conclusion, the overall, general problem with the shown code is improper object lifetime in C++. Especially when multiple execution threads are involved, it is critical for all objects' lifetimes to be well-defined, in order to avoid undefined behavior. It's the code's responsibility to ensure that all objects remain in scope as long as any execution thread references them, in any way. A full discussion of this topic is simply beyond the scope of a brief answer, here, and I refer you to your favorite advanced C++ textbook for more complete information, and discussion, of this topic.

Comment: `T` holds a `ThreadPool`, and in the destructor for `ThreadPool` it `.join()`s all the threads. Is that enough to keep `this` (here a `T`) alive until the threads are done accessing it? In other words: Does the object "die" when the destructor starts or when it finishes?

Comment: The `unique_ptr` for that `ThreadPool` is `T`'s member. When `T`'s (default) destructor returns it no longer exists, as an object, only it's members are, basically, zombies of sort, whose destruction commences. When those threads get joined `T` no longer exists.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. This means that if `T` had a user created destructor and in that destructor body called `reset` on the `unique_ptr ` (destroys the contained object). Then the destructor for `ThreadPool` would run before the destructor for `T` returns, which in turn means that all the `join`s happen while `T` is still alive, and then the `this` lifetime is fixed?